# Distinguishing by parameters with function templates and SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, sfinae, type-traits

I'm breaking sweat over disecting function templates to three groups: one to produce functions that take integrals, one to take floating points and one to take any other (that `ostringstream::<<` accepts). So far I can't even make it so that there are two groups, like so:

```
namespace my {

template<typename T>
struct logical_not
:
    std::integral_constant<bool, !T::value>
{};

template <typename T>
using static_not = typename std::conditional<
    T::value,
    std::false_type,
    std::true_type
>::type;

template<typename T>
std::string to_string(
    const T& val, 
    typename std::enable_if< std::is_integral<T>::value >::type* = 0)
{
    // integral version (ostringstream method would be replaced by a simple algorithm that forms a string)
    std::ostringstream os;

    os << val;

    return os.str();
}


template<typename T>
std::string to_string(
    const T& val, 
    //typename std::enable_if< logical_not<std::is_integral<T>>::type >::type* = 0)
    typename std::enable_if< static_not<std::is_integral<T>> >::type* = 0)
{
    std::ostringstream os;

    os.flags(std::ios::fixed);
    os.precision(2);

    os << val;

    return os.str();
}

} // my
```

I copied the two negating functions from other answers, I left their names like so just so it's easier to distinguish. I find type traits incredibly confusing, I presume the error I get for logical_not is a wrong usage of that particular negater wrapper.

With logical_not error is `Illegal type for non-type template parameter` and with static_not in the instance of a class pointer type: `'my::to_string': no matching overloaded function found`.

Please show me in the right direction if you can! My point is to add a faster implementation (without allocating for ostringstream instance) for integral types, adjust precision with floating point ones and have a function that handles the other types. Most likely no "negater" wrapper would be required for the final version, though I'd be curious why they won't work.

EDIT:
I've realized I'd need 4 groups, 4th being boolan (since boolen is an integral type as well). So building on top of max66's answer, modifying one function and adding another, the intended functionality is achieved:

```
template<typename T>
std::string to_string(
    const T& val, 
    typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_same<bool, T>::value
    >::type* = 0)
{
    return val ? "true" : "false";
}

template<typename T>
std::string to_string(
    const T& val, 
    typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_integral<T>::value
        &&  (false == std::is_same<bool, T>::value)
    >::type* = 0)
{
    return "integral, but not bool";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simpler than you think.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
std::string to_string(
    const T& val, 
    typename std::enable_if< std::is_integral<T>::value
                           >::type * = nullptr)
 { return "case integral"; }

template<typename T>
std::string to_string(
    const T& val, 
    typename std::enable_if< std::is_floating_point<T>::value 
                           >::type * = nullptr)
 { return "case floating"; }

template<typename T>
std::string to_string(
    const T& val, 
    typename std::enable_if<    (false == std::is_integral<T>::value)
                             && (false == std::is_floating_point<T>::value)
                           >::type * = nullptr)
 { return "case generic"; }

int main ()
 {
   std::cout << to_string(0) << std::endl;        // print case integral
   std::cout << to_string(0.0) << std::endl;      // print case float
   std::cout << to_string("0.000") << std::endl;  // print case generic
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works beautifully. Interestingly I have barely encountered examples where there is such boolean logic with type traits, including Bjarne's reference book.

Comment: Why don't you use a `std::enable_if<! std::is_integral<T>::value && ! std::is_floating_point<T>::value` instead of `(false == ...)`?

Comment: @em2er - well... I suppose it's question of personal taste but, reading it, I find `false == variable` clearer than `! variable`